# Developing on the ipad and will this help productivity

Tags: ipad

Can the ipad be a productivity improvement tool for software developers. What tools are out there to help while being away from my main work station or laptop ?

Are there remote tools available and is touch screen in this case a positive or negative factor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [iTap RDP](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itap-rdp-remote-desktop-for/id317062064?mt=8).  I VPN in and use that app to get instant access to my workstation without actually having to be there.  I wouldn't do ***a lot*** of work there, but it's great for doing those one or two things that 'gee if I was at my desk...' could solve.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. I agree it is more for 'gee if I was at my desk ..'

Answer (score 0):

"...help while being away..." Help with what?

Most of your stadard remote tools are available (SSH, RDP, VNC) but I would think in general they would be a lot more beneficial to sysadmins who can resolve problems without being at their desk, or in the office (Jump Desktop + VPN + 3G = WIN when a service crashes when you are at a conference).

However, I don't see how it would help with software development at all.